# What is the reason for using a wildcard import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have just learnt about importing modules, and I am a bit confused about the wildcard import.

```py
from module_name import *
```

I do not understand the reason of using it at all, I see people saying not to use it at all.

Could someone clarify what it really means, and why would one use it?

Comment: it means you import everything of the module and you have small modules where it can but at realy big modules you will get a lot of loading time and your program will become realy slow

Comment: If you're going  to use every thing which was exported from a module, then importing each thing individually is a redundant, isn't it? Your other option is to import only the `module` and then use `module.thing` everywhere. Neither solution yields good looking code

Comment: Suppose you have a module util.py with 100 functions. Now that you want to use 50 of them, you might want to use `from util import *` instead of importing them one by one.

Comment: One example why wildcard imports are bad: Do `import os` and wonder why [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) suddenly doesn't work like [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) anymore.

Comment: @Matthias i think you meant `from os import *`

Comment: @reportgunner: That was an `OutOfCoffeeError`. You're right.

Comment: haha I was just running my `moar_coffee()` routine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [[Python.Docs]: Modules - More on Modules](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#modules) (**emphasis** is mine):

> There is even a variant to import all names that a module defines:
>
> ```py
> >>> from fibo import *
> >>> fib(500)
> 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377
> ```
>
> This imports all names except those beginning with an underscore (`_`). In most cases Python programmers **do not use this facility since it introduces an unknown set of names into the interpreter, possibly hiding some things you have already defined**.
>
> Note that in general the practice of importing `*` from a module or package **is frowned upon, since it often causes poorly readable code**. However, it **is okay to use it to save typing in interactive sessions**.

So, it means: importing **all** (check the above page for the ***__all__*** variable meaning) **symbols** exported by a module / package into the **current namespace**.

Generally (as the above states), it's used when one is in the console and wants to save time by not importing everything needed, "manually". 
It's also used by some who don't know what to import (so they import everything, since they don't really know what they're doing - there are exceptions of course, but those are rare).

**Anyway**, probably **this is the most eloquent example** (as it **only** relies on *Python*): illustrating its pitfalls:

> ```py
> >>> with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
> ...     f.write("DON'T USE wildcard imports!")
> ...
> 27
> >>>
> >>> from os import *
> >>>
> >>> with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
> ...     f.write("USING wildcard imports ...")
> ...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
> ```

The wildcard import shadows:

- [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)

by:

- [[Python.Docs]: os.open(path, flags, mode=0o777, *, dir_fd=None)](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.open)

Things can get even messier when dealing with 3<sup>rd</sup>-party modules (where the collision hit chance can grow exponentially).

Comment: @Jperkins98: did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

`from module import *` generally imports evey name from a given module (though the module may use `__all__` to restrict that). It's generally best avoided, since this set of names may change over time, possibly changing the names available to your code.

I do sometimes use it in interactive sessions as a convenience, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is used for importing everything from the module. The reason why you are recommended not to use it, is because it can get confusing as to where the function or class you are using came from. Moreover, some things might have the same name in different modules, and importing them like this would overwrite the one previously imported.

Comment: Here is a reference for this statement: According to PEP8 "Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided" (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).