# CodeBlocks compilation error. Cin was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

When i want to compile a code, is giving me an error... cout and cin was not declared in this scope. What's the problem?

I searched on google. They said i need to reinstall codeblocks. I have done this and is not working.

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int n,z,c;
    cin>>n;
    z=0;
    while(n>0)
    {
        c=n%10;
        n=n/10;
        if(c<5)
        {
            z=z*10+2*c;
        }
    }
    cout << z;

    return 0;
}
```

It should compile it...

Comment: use std::cin. It is located inside the std namespace! Same for cout.
 or using namespace std;

Comment: Your code formatting is terrible, please learn ho to do that correctly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: The names of the objects are respectively `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Comment: i think you need to add `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this `using namespace std;` after `#include <iostream>` . Or use `std::cin` `std::cout`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice please.

Answer (score 0):

Also posting the 3<sup>rd</sup> way (compromise between the 2 existing answers - was already mentioned in the comments), which I think works best for the current scenario. This is my favorite one (well, excepting cases when I use lots of stuff from a namespace).

Add:

```cpp
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
```

after the `#include`. This way:

- You avoid `using namespace X;` hell. That's a big *NO-NO*, there are lots of resources explaining why (you could check [[SO]: what is the reason for using a wildcard import? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722260/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-wildcard-import/55722824#55722824) for an equivalent in *Python*)
- You don't have to type the fully qualified name every time (just the plain name). Using *FQN*s can be / is:

  - Very annoying (especially when dealing with nested namespaces)
  - Safe
  - Easier to read

Answer (score -1):

Addding `std::cin` or `std::cout` would fix it
If you don't want to add std:: again and again then
You can also add `using namespace std;` just after `#include<iostream>`

---

This happens because cin and cout are  members of standard library.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is probably not a good hint. This will bring the whole `std` namespace into the global namespace. `using std::cout; using std::cin;` is prefered instead.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice please.