# what is difference between "import module" and "from module import *"

Tags: python

I am new in python and trying to understand the difference between "import module" and "from module import *". I was thinking both are the same as they import all the functions from the module but doesn't see so. My confusion stems from the below code--

```
import abc
class Minnn(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def calculate(self, x):
        pass  # empty body, no c
```

When I run, I get the following error saying "NameError: name 'ABC' is not defined". When I replace the first import line with "from abc import *" then it works. So why is this causing a difference

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import, besides it depends on where `ABC` is defined inside the `abc` module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270954/difference-between-import-x-and-from-x-import

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722260/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-wildcard-import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing a module adds a single symbol into the namespace, but from which you can reference exported objects:

```
# simple import
import abc

abc.ABC
abc.ABCMeta

# renamed via "as"
import abc as module
module.ABC
module.ABCMeta
```

When you `import *`, you are adding all exported symbols from that module into the current namespace, and so you can reference them directly without the module prefix:

```
#### YOU PROBABLY SHOULD NOT DO THIS
from abc import *
####

ABC
ABCMeta
```

If you're hacking in a shell or notebook; not a big deal. But production code should not do this.

Comment: Since @user496934 is new to the language, maybe you should include that import * is bad form.