# Ctypes- pass the address of an integer to WriteProcessMemory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers, winapi, ctypes

I want to write to `address1` the value of `number1` that is an integer. I tried to use `addressof` but it still doesn't work. what is the equivalent of `&` from c++?

```
windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_char_p, c_int, c_void_p]
windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.restype = c_void_p
address1 = 0xa9a010
number1 = 0x140000000
lpNumberOfBytesWritten = c_size_t(0)
if windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(
        hProcess,
        c_char_p(address1),
        addressof(c_char_p(number1)),
        sizeof(c_void_p),
        byref(lpNumberOfBytesWritten)) == 0:
    error()
```

The desired output is *address1=0x140000000 but it contains other value

Comment: Please also include your values (and any variables used).

Comment: @CristiFati address1 = 0xa9a010 , number1 = 0x140000000. I want- *address1=0x140000000

Comment: You should add that in the question. Also *lpNumberOfBytesWritten*

Comment: What's *lpNumberOfBytesWritten* value? what's the other value? Is it the same than before writing it? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First,** `sizeof(c_void_p) = 4;`

Because `0x140000000` exceeds four bytes, it will be truncated.

[image: 1]

You can see that under the same environment, the results of `0x40000000` and `0x140000000` are the same.

You need to change `sizeof(c_void_p)` to `sizeof(c_longlong)`

**Second,** According to [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory)'s function prototype

```
BOOL WriteProcessMemory(
  HANDLE  hProcess,
  LPVOID  lpBaseAddress,
  LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  SIZE_T  nSize,
  SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesWritten
);
```

You can see the type of `lpBuffer` is `VOID*`

So you need to change `windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_char_p, c_int, c_void_p]` to `windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_int, c_void_p]`

**Finally, this is the modified code.**

```
windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_int, c_void_p]
windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.restype = c_void_p
address1 = 0xa9a010
number1 = 0x140000000
lpNumberOfBytesWritten = c_size_t(0)
if windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(
        hProcess,
        c_char_p(address1),
        addressof(c_longlong(number1)),
        sizeof(c_longlong),
        byref(lpNumberOfBytesWritten)) == 0:
    error()
```

**Note:** When checking `* address1` at `hProcess`, you should also pay attention to the type and use long type to check `address1`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, it worked!

Comment: There are some incorrect things in the answer, starting with `sizeof(c_void_p) = 4`, which is only true for (now starting to become obsolete) *32bit*.

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

There is a number of problems (besides the question lacking some info):

- When working with *ctypes* functions (e.g. `ctypes.addressof`), you should consider that they operate on ***ctypes*** (not *Python*) types. Therefore, *number* must be converted to a *ctypes* type (that should fit its value). Creating a pointer from its value is a recipe for disaster
- Generally, importing everything in the current namespace is not a good idea ([[SO]: What is the reason for using a wildcard import? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722260/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-wildcard-import/55722824#55722824))
- Your [[MS.Docs]: WriteProcessMemory function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory) definition is a bit wrong (not critical), but it's best to use existing aliases (for readability's sake)

Here's a working variant.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes


def main():
    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL("kernel32.dll")

    GetCurrentProcess = kernel32.GetCurrentProcess

    GetCurrentProcess.argtypes = []
    GetCurrentProcess.restype = wintypes.HANDLE

    WriteProcessMemory = kernel32.WriteProcessMemory
    WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.LPVOID, wintypes.LPCVOID, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)]
    WriteProcessMemory.restypes = wintypes.BOOL

    buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"0123456789")
    print("Buffer INITIAL contents: [{0:}]".format(buf.value))
    number = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0x4847464544434241)  # 8 bytes: ASCII codes H .. A
    address = ctypes.addressof(buf)  # Mimic your address - which is the above buffer's
    bytes_to_write = ctypes.sizeof(number)
    bytes_written = ctypes.c_size_t(0)
    print("Attempting to write ({0:d} bytes) number {1:d} (0x{2:016X}) to address {3:} (0x{4:016X}) ...".format(bytes_to_write, number.value, number.value, address, address))

    res = WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), address, ctypes.addressof(number), bytes_to_write, ctypes.byref(bytes_written))
    if res:
        print("Wrote {0:d} bytes".format(bytes_written.value))
        print("Buffer FINAL contents: [{0:}]".format(buf.value))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057768711]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Buffer INITIAL contents: [b'0123456789']
> Attempting to write (8 bytes) number 5208208757389214273 (0x4847464544434241) to address 1807564046992 (0x000001A4DB368290) ...
> Wrote 8 bytes
> Buffer FINAL contents: [b'ABCDEFGH89']
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- As seen, the memory contents at the specified address was successfully written
- The only "abnormal" thing is that the number had the *ASCII* codes ***['H' .. 'A']***, but in the buffer they appear reversed. That is because my *PC* is *Little-endian*. If you care to take a look, I covered this topic in [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990060/python-struct-pack-behavior/38003729#38003729)