# Why are some modules imported with "*" and some not?

Tags: python

Why for some modules do we type a '*' for example:

```
from tkinter import *
```

and for some of them we don't, like this one:

```
import time
```

Comment: do you mean `from tkinter import *`

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/19330634) help you ?

Comment: You can use `import tkinter`; there's no obligation to use `from tkinter import *`, and in fact it's better not to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually it doesn't work without '*'

Comment: @Arian, that's untrue. You just need to prefix the things you get from it with `tkinter.` when you don't do the wildcard import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When importing a package, objects from the package are in a namespace, e.g.,

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

But when explicitly importing objects from a package, they are imported into the global namespace, e.g.,

```
from time import sleep
sleep(1)
```

When using `*` instead of a list of object names, *all* objects from the package are imported into the global namespace and can be used without specifying the package name.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: I like this answer because it is concise, very easy to understand, and doesn't have all the "why this is bad and you shouldn't do it" arguments attached  -- maybe it could be added to the first question linked at the top [what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-wildcard-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722260/what-is-the-reason-for-using-a-wildcard-import).